# Suppose $m,n$ are positive integers such that $a-b|a^m-b^n , \forall a,b \in \mathbb Z , a-b \ne0$ , then is it true that $m=n$?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Suppose $m,n$ are positive integers such that for all $a\neq b$ one has $a-b\mid a^m-b^n$, then is it true that $m=n$ ?

Comment: One should never use $\forall$ as an afterthought. I edited the question body to make it less pain to read.

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ For all $\,b\ne a\,$ we deduce $\, a\!-\!b\mid a^m\!-a^n\  [\,= a^m\!-b^n + b^n\!-a^n]\ $ hence $\,\ldots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You need to show that the above condition implies $2^m-2^n\equiv 0\pmod d$ for all $d$. So $2^m=2^n$.

Comment: Umm , why $2^m-2^n$ ?

Comment: Because $(2+d)^m-2^n$ is divisible by $d$. @SaunDev And $(2+d)^m-2^m$ is divisible by $d$.

Comment: and then we expand $(2+d)^m$ binomially to get $d|2^m-2^n$ , right ?

Comment: Right. @SaunDev